# How to stack/align images in CSS/Bootstrap horizontally regardless of orientation?

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble with showing stacked images. I'm using Bootstrap and I'm displaying all pictures in a model with Django (no issues with Django here).

[Here is what the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3USTA.jpg)

I know this is down to flexbox, and I've searched and used various things like wrap, align-items, justify content etc and while I can get the landscape images to align with the bottom of the portrait ones in one line, what I want to make them do is all stack together like the way the images are stacked on this website: https://unsplash.com/

Various orientations all stacking horizontally together nicely. Here is my code (the {code} is just pulling data from Django models, it adds each picture in a loop)

```
<div class="row my-4 text-center mx-auto w-auto flex-wrap align-items-start">
    {% for picture in object_list %}
    <div class="col mx-auto centered mb-3">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="card mx-auto text-center" style="width: 25em">
                <img src="{{ picture.front_image.url }}" class="card-img-top p-3" alt="Picture">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">{{ picture.name }}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have asked the question after looking at other questions and guides and have tried various things, mostly changing the top div to include various Bootstrap classes, but I haven't been able to get the effect I want.

Any help or advice appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to use a javascript library to do it.
This type of layout is called Masonry layout.

Refer the following link for more info on how to implement it

[Masonry Layout](https://masonry.desandro.com/) (Requires Jquery)

Alternative to this library [Macy.js](http://macyjs.com/) (Pure javascript)

More libraries

https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

http://callmecavs.com/bricks.js/